# Javascript: how to move div or span around the screen without changing the style properties of the element being moved?

Tags: javascript, optimization

I noticed its very slow to use `parseInt` to retrieve a `style` attribute for comparison and then assign it back with "px". How can I avoid this parsing between string to int and then back to string ? Basically I need it for optimizing a heavy script which moves things around the screen and changing the `left` property doesn't cut it. Any other options ?

PS: How does jQuery move a div, say 10 px to the left ? Does it also change the style object ?

Comment: jQuery changes the style object.

Comment: @Zevan: thanks responding, I think I have to scroll the elements instead of relocating them. It's much faster; the scirpt on this page shows how http://www.mioplanet.com/rsc/newsticker_javascript.htm

Answer (score 0):

Don't read property in object every time - it is slow and inacurate. Keep your own internal track with pure number in variable.

```
var divPosition = 0
function moveDiv()
    divPosition = divPosition + 10
    divElement.style.left = divPosition + "px"
end
```